# Select only the string from array that has triggered jQuery function()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, html-table

I have looked for a previous answer to this question with no success. I am not very familiar with JS, or jQuery for that matter (but I'm learning).

I am trying to assign a class of `.active` to all `<td>` cells in whatever column the mouse enters into.

Here is a simplified version of my markup:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td class="js col one">1</td>
      <td class="js col two">2</td>
      <td class="js col three">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td class="js col one">2</td>
      <td class="js col two">4</td>
      <td class="js col three">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td class="js col one">3</td>
      <td class="js col two">6</td>
      <td class="js col three">9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my script:

```
var arr = ['.one', '.two', '.three'];
var tableCol = $('.js.col' + arr);

tableCol.mouseenter(function() {
    tableCol.addClass('active');
});
tableCol.mouseleave(function() {
    tableCol.removeClass('active');
});
```

I have placed the differing classes into an array because in my real code there are a lot more than 3 different columns and I don't want to repeat myself.

The problem I am facing is that on `.mouseenter` of any of these columns, triggers the `.addClass` for all strings in the array. Is there a way to only `.addClass` to the specific string from the array that has triggered the function?

I hope I have made myself clear.

Comment: `tableCol[0].mouseenter` - start from there, or go with the
`$(this).mouseenter` - which is much better.

Comment: This throws me an error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another solution. This one utilizes the classes to highlight the columns.

```
var arr = ['.one', '.two', '.three'];
var tableCol = $('.js.col' + arr);

tableCol.mouseenter(function() {
        var colClass = "." + $(this).attr("class").split(" ").join(".")
        $(colClass).addClass('active')
});
tableCol.mouseleave(function() {
    $(tableCol).removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: This has worked! Thank you. So in this instance `$(this)` has successfully isolated the string in the array that has triggered the function?

Comment: Correct. As you saw in the other answers you can use $(this) within your event functions to access the element that triggered it. So yes in this case we are using $(this) to get that elements class attribute. Which gives us the string "js col one" for example. Split will make it into an array {'js', 'col', 'one'} and join will put the array together as a string "js.col.one". Your arr array is only used to add the mouseenter and mouseleave events.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation. Much appreciated. Have upvoted and ticked answered.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

#### By class

```js
var arr = ['.one', '.two', '.three'];
var tableCol = $('.js.col' + arr);

tableCol.mouseenter(function() {
    /*
     * $(this).attr('class')
     * Get "js col one" for example of the current <td> hovered
     *
     * .split(" ")
     * Create an array with all classname values
     *
     * .join(" ")
     * Create a string with all classname values concat with "."
     * js.col.one
     *
     * Don't forget to add a "." at start and get : ".js.col.one"
     */
    var attrClass = '.' + $(this).attr('class').split(" ").join(".");
    $(attrClass).addClass('active');
});
tableCol.mouseleave(function() {
    tableCol.removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td class="js col one">1</td>
      <td class="js col two">2</td>
      <td class="js col three">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td class="js col one">2</td>
      <td class="js col two">4</td>
      <td class="js col three">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td class="js col one">3</td>
      <td class="js col two">6</td>
      <td class="js col three">9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

#### By index

```js
var arr = ['.one', '.two', '.three'];
var tableCol = $('.js.col' + arr);

tableCol.mouseenter(function() {
    /*
     * Get the index of the current td hovered
     * .index() starts to one
     * 
     */
    var index = $(this).index() - 1;
    /*
     * Set all tds at position `index - 1`
     * .eq() starts to zero
     * 
     */
    $('tr').find('td:eq('+index+')').addClass('active');
});
tableCol.mouseleave(function() {
    tableCol.removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td class="js col one">1</td>
      <td class="js col two">2</td>
      <td class="js col three">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td class="js col one">2</td>
      <td class="js col two">4</td>
      <td class="js col three">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>3</th>
      <td class="js col one">3</td>
      <td class="js col two">6</td>
      <td class="js col three">9</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

- [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)
- [.index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/)

Comment: I have only just seen this answer. This is successfully isolating the string in the array that is triggering the function?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use $(this)

```
tableCol.mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
tableCol.mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but same problem as with first answer—`$(this)` only highlights the specific `<td>` cell and I need to highlight the entire column...

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = ['.one', '.two', '.three'];
var tableCol = $('.js.col' + arr);

tableCol.mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).parent().find(tableCol).addClass('active');
});
tableCol.mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).parent().find(tableCol).removeClass('active');
});
```

I think $this will solve up your problem